# Wordpress change URL and Permalink

Tags: wordpress, apache2

I'm running a wordpress installation on a vps server.
i set it up with Wordpress URL and Site Address but i have to change it:

```
Wordpress URL: http://111.111.111.111/example.de
Site Address http://111.111.111.111/example.de
```

now i want to change it to

Wordpress URL: http://myspace.com
Site Address: http://myspace.com

i did it like this:

https://wpengine.com/resources/change-domains-wordpress/

but i still get 404 not found for every url.

i tried some rewrite different rules as well.

In addition i think i have to change all DB entries where the old ip is used instead of the new domain.
And i want to change the permalinks but this is the last step.

my problem: if you browse mydomain.de i get the default apache site. at the moment i have to use
http://domain.tld/www-dir/*  if i use http://mydomain.de/mydomain.de/* i am redirected to http://IP/mydomain.de/*

my goal: browse domain and see my website^^ and i dont want a redirect to any ip address url

any advices?

Comment: Is your DNS record set up correctly? I'n not sure what exactly you mean by `http://domain.tld/www-dir/` but it looks like you mean you need to include the "www" folder in the URL for it to work?

Comment: Hi yeah sure. My dns reach the server. i use azure dns for it.

wordpress is installed in var/www/html/mydomain.de
if i use  http:// IP or http://mydomain.de i see the default page of the apache from
if i use http:// IP/mydomain.de i reach my wordpress installation / website

Comment: Yes but is it getting to the correct directory on your server? It looks like it isn't when you say that `http://domain.tld/www-dir/` works - I don't know what www-dir is but I'm guessing that it is "www"?

Comment: wordpress is installed in var/www/html/mydomain.de
if i use  http:// IP or http://mydomain.de i see the default page of the apache from
if i use http:// IP/mydomain.de i reach my wordpress installation / website

Comment: Is the domain *supposed* to be "mydomain.de/mydomain.de"?  Or is the domain pointing to the "www" directory instead of "mydomain.de" itself, which is why you have to add "mydomain.de" as a folder to the domain?

Comment: the Domain got a A-Record to the server IP thats all. 
The Goal ist that i can reach my wordpress site under **"mydomain.de"**

Comment: Maybe i can clarify my thoughts a bit:

i want to point with a A-record to my server for all domains and subdomains.
A-records : 
Site1 - IP
Site2 - IP
Site3 - IP
subdomain.Site1 -IP

on the server i want to use var/www/html as the Site directory with a new folder for each site or subdomain

in best chase the apache server should route all requests for all Sites to the right DocumentRoot

Comment: It doesn't look like its the WP setup that's the problem, and it doesn't look like its the htaccess either. So the other other thing I can put it down to is the domain. However that isn't my area at all - I always using hosting providers for my clients - but it looks to me like you need to add something on the server so that is knows to use the "mydomain.de" folder when the mydomain.de domain is used.

Answer (score 0):

In your case, i'm not sure whether you change the server, you may only need to do step 4.

1. Copy all files to the new server.
2. Copy Database to the new server.
3. Adjust database settings in `wp-config.php`
4. Search and replace old Domainname with new Domainname in the whole Database.

For the last step i often use the [Database Search and Replace Script in PHP](https://interconnectit.com/products/search-and-replace-for-wordpress-databases/) from interconnect/it.

e.g. search for `http://111.111.111.111` and replace it with `http://myspace.com